# Finding the 10001st Prime Number - Project Euler

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I am trying to find the 10,001th prime number. I have looked at other code people have written , but I don't really understand what it means. I have written some code in JavaScript in which I tried to use the Sieve Of Eratosthenes. I'm not sure what the problem is. It looks as if it should work correctly, but I'm getting the wrong answer.

```
var compute = function() {
var prime = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19];
for(var i=20; i<=80000;i++) {
if(i%2!==0 && i%3!==0 && i%5!==0 && i%7!==0 && i%11!==0 && i%13!==0 && i%17!==0 &&      i%19!==0) {
 prime.push(i);
  }
 }  
 console.log(prime[10000]);
};

 compute();
```

Comment: 31*37=1147, so 1147 is not a prime, but your condition will recognize it as a prime.

Comment: A simple Google search: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#JavaScript

Comment: This can be optimized by only checking numbers that end in 1 3 7 or 9 instead of incrementing by one.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd How would you go about doing that?

Comment: start i at 1 and increment it in a cycle of. 2, 4, 2, 2... i. e. i = 1 + 2 = 3 + 4 = 7 + 2 = 9 + 2 = 11... repeat cycle of incrementation. You'd have to modify how you do your loop of course, but it would save a lot of time, especially when you get up there and a lot of calculations must be done to confirm a specific number.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd not sure how I would create a cycle like that. Would I do that in statement 3 of the for loop or add something to the body of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple method, but to find the millionth

(or even hundred thousandth in some machines)

you'll need to chop it up with timeouts,

or ship it off to a webworker to keep from locking up.

You only need to check the prime divisors, as you collect them,

since every number is either the product of primes

or is itself prime.

```
function nthPrime(nth){
    var P= [2], n= 3, div, i, limit,isPrime;
    while(P.length<nth){
        div= 3, i= 1;
        limit= Math.sqrt(n)+1;
        isPrime= true;
        while(div<limit){
            if(n%div=== 0){
                isPrime= false;
                div= limit;
            }
            else div= P[i++] || div+ 2;
        }
        if(isPrime) P.push(n);
        n+= 2;
    }
    return P[P.length-1];
}
```

**alert(nthPrime(10001));**

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I tried to break it down to try and understand it, but I was unable to. The 2nd while loop is tripping me up. Anyway I'll rate your answer.

Comment: @TGarr It's a nieve solution that finds all the primes. To check if a number `n` is prime, you only have to ensure that it's not divisible by every prime `{ p | p <= sqrt(n) }`  That's what this solution does.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not implement the sieve of Eratosthenes. You have to implement the following  steps (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

1. Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 to n: (2, 3, 4, ...,
   n).
2. Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
3. Starting from p, count up in increments of p and mark each of these numbers
   greater than p itself in the list. These will be multiples of p: 2p,
   3p, 4p, etc.; note that some of them may have already been marked.
4. Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked.
   If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now equal this
   number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.

If you want to find the 10001st prime number, you have to choose n large enough, so that the resulting array includes at least 10001 elements, then choose the 10001st element as result.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really not understanding how to do this. Reading through the Sieve of Eratosthenes again really didn't help things either. There has to be a less complicated answer.