# Euler 7 Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help with this code? It's supposed to get the 10,001th prime number. I know the is_prime function works to test if a number is prime since I successfully utilized this code for a previous problem. Now I'm just trying to call that in a for loop until counter hits what I want, while storing the most recent number into a variable 'holder' and printing holder at the end.

```
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    for (var i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function getBigPrime () {
var holder = 0;
var counter = 0;
    for (var k=3; counter<=10000; k+=2) {
        if (is_prime(k)) 
            holder = k; 
            counter += 1;
    }
    console.log(holder);
}

getBigPrime();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074244/finding-the-10001st-prime-number-project-euler

Comment: I don't think the loop works properly. If i change 'counter' in the for statement of the loop to different numbers, my result doesn't change.

Comment: @CBIII thanks for pointing there, I hadn't found that one. Seems he uses a dif method and I still am confused why my code doesn't work though!

Comment: You have a scoping issue. counter is being incremented when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping error with counter. 
For your for loop you can initialize `counter = 1;` to account for 2 and leave as is

http://jsfiddle.net/XtTYm/2/

```
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    var sq = Math.sqrt(num);
    for (var i=2; i<=sq; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    function getBigPrime () {
    var holder = 0;
    var counter = 1;
        for (var k=3; counter<=10000; k+=2) { 
            if (is_prime(k)){ 
                holder = k; 
                counter += 1; // should be inside the if
            }
        }
        console.log(holder);
    }

    getBigPrime();
```

Comment: You're putting `sq` into the global scope by omitting `var`.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the brackets for an `if` block, only the first line will actually be part of your block. Your current `if` statement behaves like this:

```
if (is_prime(k)) {
    holder = k; 
}

counter += 1;
```

Also, your loop skips 2, the first prime number.